# OneToOne Field django

Tags: django, one-to-one

I have the following models

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    #fields....


class EntryHistory(models.Model):
     entry = models.OneToOneField(Entry, related_name='history')
     text =.....etc
```

But when i try to access entry.history I get a DoesNotExist exception

code in shell

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk = 4)
entry_history = entry.history
    raise self.related.model.DoesNotExist
DoesNotExist
```

I want to check if an entry_history has been added for the specific entry. So i want to get the entry.history and check

```
if entry_history:
```

to see if there was an entry_history or not. What does the DoesNotExist mean?

```
 hasattr(entry, 'history')
```

returns false also.

EDIT: 
SQL table creation code

```
CREATE TABLE "mycal_entryhistory" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "entry_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE, "text" text NULL, "doctor_id" integer NOT NULL)
```

Does that mean that my table wasn't created properly?

Comment: Er, it means there is no EntryHistory for that Entry. Not sure what is unclear here.

Comment: Well i was expecting an empty or a None value, that's why it seemed a bit wierd...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if an entry_history has been added for the specific entry and `related.model.DoesNotExist` means that it does not exists, so the exception is an answer to your question.

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=4)
try:
    entry_history = entry.history
    # if this code runs it means the object exists
except entry.history.model.DoesNotExist:
    # it does not exist
```

Alternatively you can use count:

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=4)
if entry.history.count():
    # it does exist
```

Comment: Yes i thought it worked like ForeighnField, that would give me an empty or none value.Thank you for your help

Comment: rushed in to accepting...it gives me this:
'Entry' object has no attribute 'related'

Comment: had to use ObjectDoesNotExist from django.core.exception. related.model.DoesNotExist didn't seem to work for me

Comment: As [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one) suggest, besides `try`/`except`, you can use `hasattr` to avoid catching exception: `hasattr(entry, 'history')`.